# LXC not respecting netmask on Ubuntu 14

Tags: ubuntu, bridge, lxc, ubuntu-14.04

I have a LXC machine configured with bridging so that it has its own public IP address and is accessible over the internet.  Even though it's working, the netmask address set in the VMs */etc/network/interfaces* is not being kept.

The interface *eth0* on the VM is set to an inet static configuration.  The address and gateway fields are correct but the netmask is 255.0.0.0, whereas it should be 255.255.255.0.

Setting the inet to manual and letting LXC do the network configuration by specifying the *lxc.network.ipv4* and *lxc.network.gateway* parameters in the host's */var/lib/lxc/my-vm/config* results in the same problem.

Should I fix this by specifying the gateway and netmask with a *post-up route*, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Have try tried setting the network mask on lxc.network.ipv4 like:

```
lxc.network.ipv4 = 192.168.0.100/24
```